# Where().First vs Find()

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core and are in doubt about what is the most efficient solution?

Solution 1:

```
_dbContext.View.Find(topicId);
```

Solution 2:

```
_dbContext.View.Where(v => v.TopicId.Equals(topicId)).First();
```

Solution 1 is very clear to understand. Find the first result and return. But, what about solution 2? Will it search through the whole database with the Where function and then return the first result in the list. Or will it take First into consideration and stop searching through the database, when the first result is found?

Comment: This is the point of `IQueryable<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>` - they both are designed to find a solution lazily without doing too much work. `IQueryable<T>` translates the expression into a single SQL statement that returns just one value. `IEnumerable<T>` lazily iterates the collection one element at a time, so the `.First()` immediately stops the iteration when the `.Where` produces the first value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the point of `IQueryable<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>` - they both are designed to find a solution lazily without doing too much work.

`IQueryable<T>` translates the expression into a single (hopefully, but not always) SQL statement that returns just one value.

`IEnumerable<T>` lazily iterates the collection one element at a time, so the `.First()` immediately stops the iteration when the `.Where(...)` produces the first value.